# I want to make a pie chart visible and a line chart invisible when i click a button

Tags: javafx

I am trying to make charts, but I am stuck now. I have a document where I get challenges to do. I am new to JavaFX and I am trying to get 2 charts to work when I click a button. I have a line chart and a pie chart. The charts arent working because I dont have data in it. What I want is to click "pie chart" and the pie chart is showing and the message says "Drawing a pie chart". The pie chart wont show because there is no data, but that is not the point right now. I made the charts invisible en when I click one of the charts one will be visible and the other one invisible. This is everything I tried but it didnt work. If you didnt understand just comment and I will try to help.

Controller

```
package ala.javafxchart;



import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class MainSceneController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private PieChart pieChart;

    @FXML
    private LineChart lineChart;

    @FXML
    private void handlePieChartAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked the Pie Chart!");
        label.setText("Drawing a pie chart!!"); 

        pieChart.setVisible(true);
    }


    @FXML
    private void handleLineChartAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked the Pie Chart!");
        label.setText("Drawing a line chart!!");

        lineChart.setVisible(false);
    }



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }
}





    @FXML
    private void handleLineChartAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked the Pie Chart!");
        label.setText("Drawing a line chart!!");

        setVisible(lineChart);
    }

    private void setVisible(PieChart chart){

    }

    private void setVisible(LineChart chart){

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    
}
```

FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1366.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ala.javafxchart.MainSceneController">
   <children>
      <BorderPane prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1498.0">
         <top>
            <Label text="Chart Demo" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font size="35.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </top>
         <left>
            <VBox prefHeight="692.0" prefWidth="241.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="lineChart" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="245.0" text="Line Chart" />
                  <Button fx:id="pieChart" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="245.0" text="Pie Chart" />
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </left>
         <bottom>
            <Label fx:id="statusLabel" text="status message" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <padding>
                  <Insets right="1400.0" />
               </padding>
            </Label>
         </bottom>
         <center>
            <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <LineChart title="Lost Luggage 2016" visible="false">
                    <xAxis>
                      <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
                    </xAxis>
                    <yAxis>
                      <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
                    </yAxis>
                  </LineChart>
                  <PieChart title="Lost Luggage 2016" visible="false" />
               </children>
            </StackPane>
         </center>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this I made some changes to your fxml to make it more readable

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MainSceneController implements Initializable {

    public Button lineChartButton;
    public Button pieChartButton;
    public LineChart lineChart;
    public PieChart pieChart;
    public Label label;


    @FXML
    private void handlePieChartAction() {
        System.out.println("You clicked the Pie Chart!");
        label.setText("Drawing a pie chart!!");

        if(pieChart.isVisible())
            pieChart.setVisible(false);
        else
            pieChart.setVisible(true);
    }


    @FXML
    private void handleLineChartAction() {
        System.out.println("You clicked the Line Chart!");
        label.setText("Drawing a line chart!!");


        if(lineChart.isVisible())
            lineChart.setVisible(false);
        else
            lineChart.setVisible(true);
    }



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO
        lineChartButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                handleLineChartAction();
            }
        });
        pieChartButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                handlePieChartAction();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1366.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MainSceneController">
    <children>
        <BorderPane prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1498.0">
            <top>
                <Label text="Chart Demo" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="35.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
            </top>
            <left>
                <VBox prefHeight="692.0" prefWidth="241.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                    <children>
                        <Button fx:id="lineChartButton" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="245.0" text="Line Chart" />
                        <Button fx:id="pieChartButton" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="245.0" text="Pie Chart" />
                    </children>
                </VBox>
            </left>
            <bottom>
                <Label fx:id="label" text="status message" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets right="1400.0" />
                    </padding>
                </Label>
            </bottom>
            <center>
                <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                    <children>
                        <LineChart fx:id="lineChart" title="Lost Luggage 2016" visible="false">
                            <xAxis>
                                <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
                            </xAxis>
                            <yAxis>
                                <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
                            </yAxis>
                        </LineChart>
                        <PieChart fx:id="pieChart" title="Lost Luggage 2016" visible="false" />
                    </children>
                </StackPane>
            </center>
        </BorderPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I renamed your buttons to lineChartButton and pieChartButton instead of lineChart and pieChart because thats super confusing and gave ids to the pieChart and lineChart

Comment: I've changed my controller but it still doesnt work. I really dont know what to do. Your help will be appreciated. I cant even run the program.

Comment: I am going to check it out now I was busy

Comment: lambda expressions arenot supported in -source 1.7

Comment: I changed it try it now

Comment: It worked but when I clicked "linechart" the linechart is coming, but when I click piechart when I already clicked linechart, both of them show. Btw Thanks for all the help! and if you could comment the code where you changed it, it would be appreciated

Comment: If i have solved you problem I am going to let you do the rest this is your project not mine think of how you can use if statements to solve the issue you are having if this answer solved you problem please accept the answer so other people don't think this is still an open question

Comment: Hint on the showing of both try setting the other chart that was first clicked to .setVisible(false);